# How do I remove HTML and special charaters using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

So what I want to do is remove all of the HTML table tag elements, leaving the link tags alone.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
<tbody><tr valign="top"><td class="headlines">•</td><td class="headlines"><a href="" target="_top">SOME TEXT</a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

It would be nice to wrap the linked text into a div or place in a paragraph tag.

Any thoughts?

Comment: you want to remove bullet or td containing bullet?

Comment: You can probably just remove all, right..?

Comment: @MikeEase: I did not mean that ;)

Comment: Can't reproduce, same thing is working just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/smn65/ can you please elaborate and give more code? You need to call it in `$(document.ready()` function or something like that otherwise you won't have any elements yet..

Comment: can you please explain your question in detail with exact code if possible.

Comment: did you want to extract `<a href="" target="_top">SOME TEXT</a>` and completely remove the table from the DOM? Please show a before and after.

Comment: Use a jquery selector to find all the <a> tags, and then get the a.parent().html() which will give you the <a> tag completely

Answer (score 4):

#### The question was changed to ask something completely different after this answer was posted.

See [@T.J.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341617/how-do-i-remove-html-and-special-charaters-using-jquery/5341677#5341677) for a solution to the new question.

---

Do it with — ***gasp, shock horror*** — [vanilla JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)!

```
var $headlines = $('.headlines'),
    headlineText = $headlines.text(),
    replaceText = headlineText.replace(/•/g, '');

$headlines.text(replaceText);
```

or, slightly sexier syntax:

```
$('.headlines').text(function (index, text)
{
    return text.replace(/•/g, '');
});
```

Comment: That will replace the *first* bullet, rather than only a bullet at the beginning of the string. No idea whether that's what the OP wants, the question's pretty unclear. :-)

Comment: @T.J. - good point. Updated with regex to fix that. By now, it's a moot point though, given the massive change in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Woah, you *completely* changed the question with your edit. Completely.

You can process the tables in your new question, putting all the links contained by the table into a single new paragraph, like this:

```
$('table').each(function() {
  var $thisTable = $(this),
      links = $thisTable.find('a'),
      newPara;
  $thisTable.parent().append($("<p>").append(links));
  $thisTable.remove();
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/urixi3/2)

Or if you want each link in its own paragraph (probably better):

```
$('table').each(function() {
  var $thisTable = $(this),
      $parent = $thisTable.parent(),
      links = $thisTable.find('a');
  links.each(function() {
    $parent.append($("<p>").append(this));
  });
  $thisTable.remove();
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/urixi3/4)

---

Original answer, now irrelevant:

You can use [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/):

```
$(".headlines").empty();
```

...to completely empty the matching elements.

Or if you want to selectively remove *just* the `•` at the beginning, you can use [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and pass in a function:

```
$(".headlines").html(function(index, html) {
    if (html.substring(0, 1) === "•") {
        html = html.substring(1);
    }
    return html;
});
```

Or perhaps the `*` and any whitespace after it:

```
$(".headlines").html(function(index, html) {
    return html.replace(/^• */, '');  // A `•` at start of string
                                      // followed by zero or more spaces
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/inupe6/2)

...but don't do either of the latter ones that if the `headlines` elements will have complex, nested structures with event handlers on them, etc. (it's fine for basic cells, though).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but it will remove the entire element. `empty` will remove all child nodes including text or nested elements.

If you just wanted to remove all the text from elements containing dots you could do:

```
$(":contains('•')").text();
```

If you just wanted to get rid of the dots  and leave everything else:

```
    $(":contains('•')").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text.replace(/•/gi, ""))
    $(this).text(text);
    });
```

Comment: Note that the question was completely different when I answered this! Was: "I wanted to remove the bullet in between the HTML td tags."

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<div>"+$('table a').text()+"</div>").insertAfter('#whereveryouwant");
```

Comment: It's probably better to do `$("<div/>").html($("table a").text()).insertAfter("#some_id");`

Answer (score 0):

```
var $myTable = $('#myTableId'); //Add id="myTableId" to the table you want select
$myTable.replaceWith($myTable.children('a').wrapAll('<div></div>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.headlines a').parent().html();
```