# How do I remove HTML and special charaters using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove HTML and special charaters using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341617/how-do-i-remove-html-and-special-charaters-using-jquery)

So what I want to do is remove all of the HTML table tag elements, leaving the link tags alone.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
<tbody><tr valign="top"><td class="headlines">•</td><td class="headlines"><a href="" target="_top">SOME TEXT</a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

It would be nice to wrap the linked text into a div or place in a paragraph tag.

Any thoughts?